# Use jQuery to automate links to chapters within a page?

Tags: jquery, css, automation, article

The page in question: http://wlvrtn.com/sites/nms-chapters/page.php

This page currently is made of up 3 chapters, each contained in their own article tags. In the future, I'll add additional chapter articles, as well as chapter links in the floating chapter nav.

**What I'd like to achieve:**

I want to automate the chapter nav link destinations via jQuery, such that the first link in the list points to the first article on the page, the second link points to the second article, and so on.

I.e., if I add a fourth chapter article, I don't want to have to give it the id "article-04"; I want the fourth link in the chapter nav, when added, to know it should point to the new article. I'm guessing that "nth-child" plays into this, but I'm too new to know.

Thanks,
xo

---

Chapter Nav:

```
<nav id="chapters">
  <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Chapter One</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Chapter Two</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Chapter Three</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

---

Chapter Article:

```
<article class="clearfix">
  <h1>Chapter One</h1>
</article>
<article class="clearfix">
   <h1>Chapter Two</h1>
     <p>And so on...</p>
```

Comment: Did you try something ?

Comment: Even your existing links don't work. You need some selectors attached to create links automatically...first attach a class to each of the chapters and then enumerate on them to know the total chapters present. jQuery $.each() should help you :)

Comment: @theshadowmonkey, I'm a jQuery beginner in the most literal sense. Where might I read up on what you're suggesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/tXhwN/))?

```
$(function(){

    // find the nav & headers
    var nav = $('#chapters li a'),
        articles = $('#main article > h1');

    // now assign an id/href to each
    nav.each(function(i){
        nav.eq(i).attr('href', '#article-' + i);
        articles[i].id = 'article-' + i;
    });

});
```

Comment: A. How might I ease this with a graceful scroll? B. Using the article's h1 as the anchorpoint is a great start, but I'd need the anchor to start about 100px above that to display well. Possible?

Comment: Check out my [visualNav](http://mottie.github.io/visualNav/bootstrap.html) plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of jquery tutorial for anchor link scroll with jquery.
i personally use this one on one of my projects

try this tutorial:

http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/12/05/lateral-on-scroll-sliding-with-jquery/

:)

Answer (score 0):

A relatively simple approach to meeting your requirements would be this, though it could certainly be optimised:

```
$('h1').each(
    function(){
        var that = $(this),
            txt = that.text();
        that[0].id = txt.replace(/\s+/,'');

        if (!$('#toc').length){
            $('<ul />', { id : 'toc' }).prependTo('body');
        }

        var li = $('<li />').appendTo('#toc');
        $('<a />', {'href' : '#' + that.text().replace(/\s+/,''), text : that.text()}).appendTo(li);
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/LLQmy/).

References:

- jQuery:

  - [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
  - [`prependTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/prependTo/).
  - [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/).
- Plain JavaScript:

  - [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).